# Postgres/Flyway: How can I wrap long constant strings in sql file?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I want to line wrap the SQL in my flyway migration file, the working version looks like:

```
comment on table account is
'Multiple users may be associated with the same account (think multiple login methods, like gmail + facebook, etc.) ';
```

If I use IDEA and hit enter within the string it generates this:

```
comment on table account is
'Multiple users may be associated with the same account (think multiple' ||
' login methods, like gmail + facebook, etc.) ';
```

But then running the migrate operation gives the error `PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"`.

Versions: Flyway 4.2, Postgres 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to split a string across lines in SQL (without any concatenation operator):

```
comment on table account is
'Multiple users may be associated with the 
same account (think multiple login methods, 
like gmail + facebook, etc.)';
```

Comment: You're right; guess I got mislead by IDEA wanting to do string concatentation.  Though that does seem to embed the newline character into the comment.  Is there a way around that?  Though I'm kind of liking that the comment is nicely wrapped in various tools (IDEA, JOOQ comments, etc.)

Comment: Yes - the newlines are currently part of the comment.  I'm asking if there is any way to wrap the SQL source to be multiline, but without embedding the newlines in the comment.   That is, the wrapping is purely for readability of the source code.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Got it the wrong way round. No, I don't think there is a way

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer for wrapping the source code only, rather than the contents of the string :

```
comment on table account is
'Multiple users may be associated with the same account (think multiple'
' login methods, like gmail + facebook, etc.)';
```

---

Edit

This is apparently called "implicit string concatenation", and the Postgres doco says it's part of the SQL standard:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Apparently, it's originally a `C` thing: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/255021

Which makes sense and is actually why I was looking for this functionality in the first place.
80chars4life, yo.

Comment: I have been trying to find this behavior documented somewhere but have not been successful.  I can confirm that this also works for queries, e.g. the following (where \n means a new line): `select 'The quick brown fox ' \n 
'jumped over ' \n 
'the lazy dog'`

Comment: @Alchemistmatt I asked ChatGPT, and it led to me to the link I've added in the anwser.