# Implicit string concatenation in PostgreSQL for strings separated by line feeds

Tags: postgresql, operators, string-concatenation

I have observed that the following two queries are both valid in PostgreSQL, and each results in the same query result:

```
SELECT 'PostgreSQL is a powerful, '     ||
       'open source object-relational ' ||
       'database system.';

SELECT 'PostgreSQL is a powerful, ' 
       'open source object-relational '
       'database system.';
```

Those queries work both in both [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), giving

```
PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database system.
```

I have been trying to determine if the second form, where the `||` string concatenation operator is omitted, is officially supported, but have been unable to find it documented anywhere. Stack Overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884004/1179467 demonstrates that the `||` operator can also be omitted when defining a comment on an object.

Can the `||` operator be safely omitted between strings separated by newlines, or might this behavior be removed in a future release of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS:

> Two string constants that are only separated by whitespace *with at
> least one newline* are concatenated and effectively treated as if the
> string had been written as one constant. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT 'foo'
> 'bar';
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> SELECT 'foobar';
> ```
>
> but:
>
> ```
> SELECT 'foo'      'bar';
> ```
>
> is not valid syntax. (This slightly bizarre behavior is specified by
> SQL; PostgreSQL is following the standard.)